# Find out how similar a set is compared to all other sets in a collection of sets

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, similarity

I'm trying to calculate how similar a set is compared to all other sets in a collection by counting the number of elements that match. Once I have the counts, I want to perform further operations against each set with the top X (currently 100) similar sets (ones with the highest count). I have provided an example input and an output which shows the count of matching elements against two sets:

#### input

```
{
  "list1": [
    "label1",
    "label2",
    "label3"
  ],
  "list2": [
    "label2",
    "label3",
    "label4"
  ],
  "list3": [
    "label3",
    "label4",
    "label5"
  ],
  "list4": [
    "label4",
    "label5",
    "label6"
  ]
}
```

#### output

```
{
  "list1": {
    "list1": 3,
    "list2": 2,
    "list3": 1,
    "list4": 0
  },
  "list2": {
    "list1": 2,
    "list2": 3,
    "list3": 2,
    "list4": 1
  },
  "list3": {
    "list1": 1,
    "list2": 2,
    "list3": 3,
    "list4": 2
  },
  "list4": {
    "list1": 0,
    "list2": 1,
    "list3": 2,
    "list4": 3
  }
}
```

I came up with the following code, but it takes hours for an input of about 200,000 sets. The number of elements/labels in a set varies but averages about 10 elements in each set. The total number of unique label values is around 300.

```
    input = {}
    input['list1'] = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3']
    input['list2'] = ['label2', 'label3', 'label4']
    input['list3'] = ['label3', 'label4', 'label5']
    input['list4'] = ['label4', 'label5', 'label6']
    print(json.dumps(input, indent=2))
    input = {key: set(value) for key, value in input.items()}
    output = {key1: {key2: 0 for key2 in input.keys()} for key1 in input.keys()}
    for key1, value1 in input.items():
        for key2, value2 in input.items():
            for element in value1:
                if element in value2:
                    count = output[key1][key2]
                    output[key1][key2] = count + 1

    print(json.dumps(output, indent=2))
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to improve on the execution time of the above code when the number of sets is large?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: Those "further operations" will combine every one of the 200,000 sets with *its* 100 most similar other sets? So still 20,000,000 operations then?

Comment: Are the labels fairly randomly distributed, or are some labels or some combinations of labels much more common than others?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode yes "further operations" will combine every one of the 200,000 sets with its 100 most similar other sets.
The labels are fairly randomly distributed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) to avoid computing intersection with those sets that the cardinality of the intersection is 0:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from itertools import chain
from pprint import pprint

data = {
    "list1": ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
    "list2": ["label2", "label3", "label4"],
    "list3": ["label3", "label4", "label5"],
    "list4": ["label4", "label5", "label6"]
}

index = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in data.items():
    for value in values:
        index[value].append(key)

result = {key: Counter(chain.from_iterable(index[label] for label in labels)) for key, labels in data.items()}
pprint(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'list1': Counter({'list1': 3, 'list2': 2, 'list3': 1}),
 'list2': Counter({'list2': 3, 'list1': 2, 'list3': 2, 'list4': 1}),
 'list3': Counter({'list3': 3, 'list2': 2, 'list4': 2, 'list1': 1}),
 'list4': Counter({'list4': 3, 'list3': 2, 'list2': 1})}
```

If strictly needed you can include those sets with `0` intersection cardinality as follows:

```
result = {key: {k: value.get(k, 0) for k in data} for key, value in result.items()}
pprint(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'list1': {'list1': 3, 'list2': 2, 'list3': 1, 'list4': 0},
 'list2': {'list1': 2, 'list2': 3, 'list3': 2, 'list4': 1},
 'list3': {'list1': 1, 'list2': 2, 'list3': 3, 'list4': 2},
 'list4': {'list1': 0, 'list2': 1, 'list3': 2, 'list4': 3}}
```

A second alternative comes from the observation that most of the time is dedicated to find intersections of sets, therefore a faster data structure such as [roaring bitmap](https://roaringbitmap.org/) are useful:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
from pyroaring import BitMap

data = {
    "list1": ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
    "list2": ["label2", "label3", "label4"],
    "list3": ["label3", "label4", "label5"],
    "list4": ["label4", "label5", "label6"]
}

# all labels
labels = set().union(*data.values())

# lookup mapping to an integer
lookup = {key: value for value, key in enumerate(labels)}

roaring_data = {key: BitMap(lookup[v] for v in value) for key, value in data.items()}


result = defaultdict(dict)
for k_out, outer in roaring_data.items():
    for k_in, inner in roaring_data.items():
        result[k_out][k_in] = len(outer & inner)

pprint(result)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'list1': {'list1': 3, 'list2': 2, 'list3': 1, 'list4': 0},
             'list2': {'list1': 2, 'list2': 3, 'list3': 2, 'list4': 1},
             'list3': {'list1': 1, 'list2': 2, 'list3': 3, 'list4': 2},
             'list4': {'list1': 0, 'list2': 1, 'list3': 2, 'list4': 3}})
```

**Performance Analysis**

[image: Perfomance Comparison]

The above graph shows the performance on a dictionary `data` of length given by the value of the `x` axis, each value of the dictionary is a list of 10 labels randomly sampled from a population of 100. Against intuition roaring bitmap performs worst than your solution, while using an inverted index takes less than half the time (40 % approximately). The code to reproduce the above results can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mesejo/e9e709a1085266219abdf0e1d8013537)

Comment: Can ```BitMap``` take any iterable, or only a ```list```? ```BitMap(lookup[v] for v in value)``` would be more efficient.

Comment: @sj95126 It can take any iterable. Fixed it.

Comment: In my small test using 20,000 sets, each set containing 10 randomised labels from a selection of 300 possible label values, using the inverted index solution you provided is an improvement

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that most pairs of lists have no intersection, the code below should be faster. If it's not fast enough, and approximate results are OK, then you can try min-hashing (set k to lower values for more speed, higher values for more recall).

```py
input = {
    "list1": ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
    "list2": ["label2", "label3", "label4"],
    "list3": ["label3", "label4", "label5"],
    "list4": ["label4", "label5", "label6"],
}


import collections
import hashlib


def optional_min_hash(values, k=None):
    return (
        values
        if k is None
        else sorted(
            hashlib.sha256(str(value).encode("utf8")).digest() for value in values
        )[:k]
    )


buckets = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, values in input.items():
    for value in optional_min_hash(values):
        buckets[value].append(key)
output = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for key1, key2 in {
    (key1, key2)
    for bucket in buckets.values()
    for key1 in bucket
    for key2 in bucket
    if key1 <= key2
}:
    count = len(set(input[key1]) & set(input[key2]))
    output[key1][key2] = count
    output[key2][key1] = count
print(output)
```

Sample output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'list2': {'list4': 1, 'list1': 2, 'list2': 3, 'list3': 2}, 'list4': {'list2': 1, 'list4': 3, 'list3': 2}, 'list1': {'list2': 2, 'list3': 1, 'list1': 3}, 'list3': {'list1': 1, 'list2': 2, 'list3': 3, 'list4': 2}})
```

Comment: From limited testing, this answer is an improvement. Taking the top X results after calculating the counts is a bit of an arbitrary number so approximate results is OK and the min hashing idea very helpful